# Кнопки переключения кастомных чекбоксов

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Есть несколько кастомных чекбоксов и кнопки изменения их значения.  Одна устанавливает все чекбоксы в положение `true`, другая - в положение `false`. Они работают, но только до тех пор пока не изменить положение одного из чекбоксов вручную. После этого он никак не реагирует ни на одну из кнопок. Как можно это починить?

```js
let checkAll = document.querySelector(' input[type="button"]'),
    checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.subscribtions-list input'),
    unsubscribe = document.querySelector('.account-unsubscribe');

// checkboxes.forEach((item)=>{
//     item.setAttribute('checked', '');
// });

checkAll.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    checkboxes.forEach((item)=>{
        let checked = item.hasAttribute('checked');
        if(!checked){
            item.setAttribute('checked', '');
            // item.classList.add('active');
        }
    });
});

unsubscribe.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    checkboxes.forEach((item)=>{
        let checked = item.hasAttribute('checked');
        if(checked){
        item.removeAttribute('checked', '');
        // item.classList.remove('active');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
label.subscribe-name {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

label.subscribe-name:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #666666;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.subscribtions-list input[type="checkbox"] {
    appearance: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.subscribtions-list input:checked + .subscribe-name::after{
    background-color: #7CC142
}

.subscribe-form input[type="button"] {
    background: #7CC142;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 17px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 14px 30px;
    border: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

span.account-unsubscribe {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #8D8D8D;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #7CC142;
    /* text-align: end; */
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: fit-content;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="SUBSCRIBE TO ALL">
<div class="subscribtions">
  <ul class="subscribtions-list">
    <li>
      <input id="recipes" type="checkbox">
      <label for="recipes" class="subscribe-name active">New Recipes</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="gluten" type="checkbox">
      <label for="gluten" class="subscribe-name">Gluten Free Recipes</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="healthy" type="checkbox">
      <label for="healthy" class="subscribe-name">Heart Healthy Recipes</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="kids" type="checkbox">
      <label for="kids" class="subscribe-name">Healthy Kids Recipes</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="account-unsubscribe">Unsubscribe from all</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @teran, уважаемый, если код не входит на страницу по высоте, сворачивайте его, будьте добры.

Comment: @UModeL это какое-то новое правило ресурса, или ваши хотелки?

Comment: @teran, "Главная беда нашего времени - невежды, лентяи и хамы". Эх...

Comment: @UModeL а без демагогии  по существу? вопрос вполне был нормальный. Мне вполне комфортно с длинными сниппетами, они все равно лимит имеют по высоте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вам нужно выделить или снять выделение со всех чекбоксов, то нет необходимости каждый из них проверять в отдельности на true/false. При проверке и не срабатывает Ваше условие. Можно проще сделать:

```
 checkAll.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        checkboxes.forEach((item)=>{
            item.checked = true;
        });
    });
    

    unsubscribe.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        checkboxes.forEach((item)=>{
           item.checked = false;
        });
    });
```